# how to put password into sql table against delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

i have asked it recently but didnt find at first. in 4 steps i did it.i wanna learn another ways easier.

first,  created dbo.login table (put authorised admin and hashed password in it)

second, created sp_password_entry procedure to insert login table a temporary password

third,  created func_password_comparison function to compare hashed password of temporary user with hashed password of admin

last,   created tr_delete_control trigger on my table to specify is it admin or somebody else not authorised to delete

here is the codes;

----my table---

```
create table login

(

authorised_name varchar(30) not null,
password varchar(50) not null

)
```

---my inserted admin account and password---

```
insert into dbo.login values('admin',HASHBYTES('md5',convert(varchar(50),'myPassWord')))
```

---my procedure for temporary user for his password to be inserted into login table---

```
create procedure sp_password_entry
@pass varchar(30)
as
begin
insert into dbo.login values('temp',HASHBYTES('md5',convert(varchar(50),@pass))
end
```

---my function to check is he admin??--

```
create function func_password_comparison()
returns int
as
begin
declare @admin_pass varchar(50),
@temp_pass varchar(50)
set @admin_pass=(select password from dbo.login where authorised_name='admin')
set @temp_pass=(select password from dbo.login where authorised_name='temp')
if(@admin_pass=@temp_pass)
return 1
return 0
end
```

---my trigger to control delete for permitted user.at the end it also delete the inserted temp value and password---

```
create trigger tr_delete_control
on dbo.myTable
after delete
as
begin
declare @temp int
set @temp=dbo.func_password_comparison()
if exists(select * from deleted)
begin
if(@temp=1)
begin
print 'delete is permitted'
end
else
begin
raiserror('with the sp_password_entry procedure insert a password or you inserted wrong password',10,1)
rollback
end
delete from dbo.login where authorised_name='temp'
end
else if not exists(select * from deleted)
begin
delete from dbo.login where authorised_name='temp'
end
end
```

when the user writes

```
sp_password_entry 'wrongPassWord'
delete from dbo.myTable
```

it shows error and delete the inserted password from login table

or just writes

```
 delete from dbo.myTable
```

it shows delete trigger error.if he writes

```
 sp_password_entry 'myPassWord'
 delete from dbo.myTable
```

it shows 'delete is permitted' and deletes the rows, also delete the inserted password from login table

it works well but is there more useful and easier code for this operation? thanx in advance!!

Comment: Did you consider using sql server privileges and EXECUTE AS ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191291.aspx  / http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx )

Comment: thanx.very helpfull and brief way.